# .Net library for console menu driven app

Tags: .net, console, console-application

I was wondering if anyone knew of a library for .net console apps that handled all the menuing functionality.  I know its not that complex and I can just use `Console.WriteLine("...");` to write text then do `Console.ReadLine();`, but am just curious if anyone knows of something existing that would handle the menuing.  I'm likely to need submenus which would make the code complex.

(Don't ask why I have to do this...)

Comment: Why do you have to do this?

Comment: This was 4 years ago. I forgot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a C# binding to the [nCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library, found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/). It is an API that helps with writing text based interfaces.

If you are simply looking for command line parameter parsing - [commandline](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) is a good library for that.

Comment: @Tim Coker - I hope I understood your question correctly... I assumed that when you say `menu` in a console app, you need a whole text based interface :)

Comment: Yup.  Probably overkill for what I'm actually doing, but it'll work.  I saw a few curses implementations for windows, but didn't find one with good c# integration.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use [Terminal.Gui](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs) for a console driven GUI.

> I added this for reference purposes only, while searching for "Terminal.Gui" I stumbled upon this question.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 5):

You could use the NuGet library called [Spectre.Console](https://spectreconsole.net/prompts/selection).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out [EasyConsole](https://github.com/splttingatms/EasyConsole).

Has a Nuget package and supports complex menu nesting.

Comment: This seems mostly stale for years. Recently I tried to use .Net Core DI to create objects. But very difficult.

Comment: Looked promising, but it's design is weird.... not up to latest standards.