# C# Console app - How do I make an interactive menu?

Tags: c#, user-interface, menu, console-application

I'm trying to make a menu that looks similar to:

```
> Thing
  Another Thing
  Yet Another Thing
  Exit
```

Within a C# console app.
I've looked all over but can't find a library/example code for this sort of menu.

Put simply, i want to...

1. Display a menu
2. Allow the user to make a selection using the arrow keys [UP/DOWN]
3. Do different things when different options are selected [Enter]

Comment: For 2 and 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280591/how-can-i-read-user-input-from-the-console You have to redraw console screen if user press up/down.

Comment: You may want to look at gui.cs or C-sharp-console-gui-framework for interactive gui.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Main thing is to be able to capture inputs. Console can only "simulate" an interactive menu by clearing the console window and re-rendering it again.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<Option> options;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create options that you want your menu to have
            options = new List<Option>
            {
                new Option("Thing", () => WriteTemporaryMessage("Hi")),
                new Option("Another Thing", () =>  WriteTemporaryMessage("How Are You")),
                new Option("Yet Another Thing", () =>  WriteTemporaryMessage("Today")),
                new Option("Exit", () => Environment.Exit(0)),
            };

            // Set the default index of the selected item to be the first
            int index = 0;

            // Write the menu out
            WriteMenu(options, options[index]);

            // Store key info in here
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
            do
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();

                // Handle each key input (down arrow will write the menu again with a different selected item)
                if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                {
                    if (index + 1 < options.Count)
                    {
                        index++;
                        WriteMenu(options, options[index]);
                    }
                }
                if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    if (index - 1 >= 0)
                    {
                        index--;
                        WriteMenu(options, options[index]);
                    }
                }
                // Handle different action for the option
                if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    options[index].Selected.Invoke();
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
            while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.X);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        // Default action of all the options. You can create more methods
        static void WriteTemporaryMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            WriteMenu(options, options.First());
        }



        static void WriteMenu(List<Option> options, Option selectedOption)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            foreach (Option option in options)
            {
                if (option == selectedOption)
                {
                    Console.Write("> ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(option.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public Action Selected { get; }

        public Option(string name, Action selected)
        {
            Name = name;
            Selected = selected;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to modify this to work with what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the NuGet library called [Spectre.Console](https://spectreconsole.net/prompts/selection).

[image]

Or one of the libraries mentioned in this post:

[.Net library for console menu driven app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338029/net-library-for-console-menu-driven-app)

Comment: One thing about this... it requires a .net version greater than 6. Anything less and you're out of luck with Spectre.