# How to test if the user has pressed a specific number or letter in C#

Tags: c#, user-input

Basically I need to know how to test if the user presses the number 1 on their keyboard for the console to then execute a command. If they don't, they'd have to press 2 or 3, etc. for another command to be executed.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello,[user]!");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Username");
        string uname = Console.ReadLine();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.Clear();
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Axiom, " + uname);
        Console.WriteLine("If You Want To Find The Full List Of Commands, Please Press 1");
        Console.WriteLine("If Not, Then Press Esc To Exit Or Press A Command Button To Execute A Command");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [C# Console app - How do I make an interactive menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767909/c-sharp-console-app-how-do-i-make-an-interactive-menu) help?

Comment: Are you looking for Console.Read() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-5.0

Comment: This has been asked a ton of times. At least try a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+console+user+input+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Hello,[user]!");
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Username");
    string uname = Console.ReadLine();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.Clear();
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Axiom, " + uname);
    Console.WriteLine("If You Want To Find The Full List Of Commands, Please Press 1");
    if(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar == Convert.ToChar("1"))
    {
     //More Code...
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("If Not, Then Press Esc To Exit Or Press A Command Button To Execute A Command");
       //more code...
    }
```

Comment: `'1'` instead of `Convert.ToChar("1")`

Answer (score 1):

You read a single character using `Console.ReadKey(bool b)`. A `switch` statement can do the rest. E.g:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Hello,[user]!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Username");
            string uname = Console.ReadLine();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Clear();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Axiom, " + uname);
            Console.WriteLine("If You Want To Find The Full List Of Commands, Please Press 1");
            Console.WriteLine("If Not, Then Press Esc To Exit Or Press A Command Button To Execute A Command");
            char c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
            switch( c )
            {
                case '1': 
                    // do some work
                    break;
                case 'A': 
                    // do some other work
                    break;
                case '\x1B': // this is ESC
                    return;
                default: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong character!");
                    break;
            }
```

Parameter `true` in the call to `ReadKey()` prevents the user entry from being echoed to the console. Set this parameter to `false`, or skip it, if you want the user to see the entered character.